# Getting a PHP constant back from it's string name

Tags: php

I'm creating a small LDAP connection class but this applies to PHP constants in general.

PHP has constants like `LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION`, `LDAP_OPT_HOST_NAM`, and `LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT` that are used in the following function:

`ldap_set_option ( $myLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 )`

In my LDAP connection class I want to be able to pass the options in an array like so

```
array( 
'LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION' => 3,
'LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT' => 1000
);
```

I'd then like to do the following type of loop

```
foreach( $options as $option => $value ){
      ldap_set_option ( $myLdapConnection, $option, $value );
}
```

If I try this, however, I get an error that says the function expects a long, not a string. How can I get past this?

EDIT: Bart is right, I realize. I'll do it this way. It'll even be faster because there won't be a string involved.

Just to be clear though, if ever there should be overlap of constants, for example when I define my own constants, then it might be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not build your array like this:

```
array( 
    LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION => 3,
    LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT => 1000
);
```

Also keeps it working if for whatever reason PHP changes (new PHP release for example) the values of any of the constants you use.

Comment: I wouldn't want to do it this way because php might assign the same value to some of its contents. Lets pretend there are two constants, CONST_1 and CONST_2. For some reason they are both assigned the value 1. 

In your case I'd get a weird bug because this is what i'd be doing

array( 1 => 3, 1 => 1000 ). See the problem?

Comment: @Jerry If that was the case, the problem will still hold because you would `ldap_set_option` twice for the same option. As long as they are destined for the same use, flags should be different

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`constant($option)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)

Comment: @Jerry Saravia this answers your question, but I'd recommend @Bart S.'s solution for doing what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your array so that you're storing the actual constant, and not the string representation of the constant.  Like so:

```
array( 
LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION => 3,
LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT => 1000
);
```

Keep in mind that this only works so long as there's no overlap in the values of the actual constants; that would cause a collision in your array space.

Comment: I doubt that they should ever overlap, any such constants that can be passed to `ldap_set_option()` need to be unique, in order for the function to be able to distinguish between them!